# Crypto-js decryption of password shows wrong result

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mern, cryptojs

I have a register and a login in an auth.ts. I currently test it with postman. The library I use is crypto-js and I used it before in node, but this time I am using the first time TypeScript. I have installed @types/crypto-js. When I register, the correct Data is set into MongoDb. The encrypted password, that postman populates is the same as mongo displays. But when I login, postman throws the error "wrong password". I log all password const out of the file and the const inputPassword shows the correct password, but const originalPassword shows it wrong. Although it only contains numbers that I used in the password, they are in arbitrary order and the password is twice as long. I googeled this, but found no answer. Clearing cache brought no solution.

Here my auth.ts:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
const authRouter = Router();
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from "../models/user";
//register
authRouter.post('/register', async (request:Request, response:Response)=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        vorname:request.body.vorname,
        nachname:request.body.nachname,
        email:request.body.email,
        username:request.body.username,
        street:request.body.street,
        number:request.body.number,
        plz:request.body.plz,
        city:request.body.city,
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            request.body.password,
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        ).toString(),
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        response.status(200).json(savedUser);
    } catch(error){
        response.status(403)
        throw new Error('Action failed');
    }
});

//login
authRouter.post('/login', async (request:Request, response:Response)=>{
    let sec:string = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({username:request.body.username});

        if(!user){
            return response.status(401).json("Wrong credentials");
        }
        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user?.password, process.env.PASS_SEC);
        console.log(hashedPassword);
        const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.UTF8);
        console.log(originalPassword);
        const inputPassword = request.body.password;
        console.log(inputPassword);
        if(originalPassword != inputPassword){
            return response.status(401).json("Wrong password");
        } else {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            {id: user!._id,
             isAdmin:user!.isAdmin,
            },
            sec,
            {expiresIn:"30d"}
        )
        const {password, ...others} = user?._doc;
        response.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
        }
    } catch(error:any){
        response.status(401)
        throw new Error(error)
    }
});

export default authRouter;
```

Comment: You should hash your passwords using something like bcrypt, and absolutely not use symmetrical encryption. Assuming you're aware this is a terrible way to store passwords, can you share the console.log statements output?

Comment: @Evert I learned encryption with crypto-js in my mern-stack course. bcrypt I not have used yet. Here is the output: { words: [ 943141937, 842205706, 168430090, 168430090 ], sigBytes: 6 }
[0] 383734313233
[0] 874123

Answer (score 1):

I close this question, because I have thrown out crypto-js and use bcrypt, like Evert suggested it. Now it works.